# Increase count when reading all the files in a directory & print distinct Stack trace

Tags: java, java-6

***Java - 1.6***

I am reading a bunch of log files from  a directory and printing in this manner.

> Class name:- GSAItemDescriptor.java Line Number:- 7521
>   ConcurrentUpdateException occurence count: 249
>   ConcurrentUpdateException stack trace count: 1241
>
> at
>   atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItemDescriptor.updateItem(GSAItemDescriptor.java:7521)
>
> at
>   atg.adapter.gsa.ItemTransactionState.updateItemState(ItemTransactionState.java:984)
>
> at
>   atg.adapter.gsa.GSATransaction.beforeCompletion(GSATransaction.java:452)

**My Problem**

1)  `occurence count` and `stack trace count` starts from 1 when it reads a new log file.

2) How do I print the `stack trace` only once when it has already occurred  and just increase the count, which works while reading the all the log files.

**My Code**

```
class demoPractice{
  public void getConcurrentUpdateException(String sPath, BufferedWriter out2) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
      File f = new File(sPath);
      if (f.isFile()) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sPath);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String strLine;

        String sPattern = "at (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sPattern);

        boolean bFlag = false;
        int iCount = 0;
        int totCount = 0;
        int exCount = 0;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

          if ((strLine.contains("atg.repository.ConcurrentUpdateException"))){
            exCount++;
            bFlag = true;
          }
          if (bFlag) {
            if ((strLine.contains("**** Warning") || (strLine.contains("**** Error")))) {
              Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);

              if (m.find()) {
                totCount++;
                iCount++;

                if ((iCount == 1)) {
                  out2.append('\n');
                  out2.write("Class name:- " + m.group(3));

                  out2.append('\n');
                  out2.write("Line Number:- " + m.group(4));
                  out2.append('\n');

                  out2.write("ConcurrentUpdateException occurence count: " + exCount);
                  out2.append('\n');
                  out2.write("ConcurrentUpdateException stack trace count: " + totCount);
                  out2.append('\n');
                }
                if (strLine.contains("at")) {
                  String sTemp[] = strLine.split("\\s+at+\\s+");

                  strLine = sTemp[1];
                  strLine = "at   " + strLine;

                }
                out2.append('\n');
                out2.write(strLine);
                out2.append('\n');

                if (iCount == 5) {
                  bFlag = false;
                  iCount = 0;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if (br != null) {
          br.close();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
      File logsFolder = new File("D:\\Edu_logs\\Edu_logs\\");
      demoPractice objgetExc = new demoPractice();
      PrintStream out2 = null;

      out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\Edu_logs\\Edu_logs\\practice.txt"), true);
      FileWriter ff = new FileWriter("D:\\Edu_logs\\Edu_logs\\practice.txt");
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(ff);
      if (logsFolder.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listfiles = logsFolder.listFiles();
        for (File tempFileName : listfiles) {
          String sPath = tempFileName.getAbsolutePath();

          objgetExc.getConcurrentUpdateException(sPath, bw);
        }
        System.out.println("Done Prosessing");
      }
      out2.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```